# Downloadinf PDF from React native webview gives "invaild pdf format or corrupted" after opening on Android but works fine on iOS

Tags: pdf, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm using the below code to open an URL. Downloading a PDF from React native webview after opening on Android gives:

> "invaild pdf format or corrupted"

but it works fine on iOS.

```
<WebView
        renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}
        startInLoadingState={isLoading}
        renderLoading={() => {
          return <BarIndicator color="blue" />;
        }}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{
          uri: webviewUrl,
          headers: webviewHeaders,
        }}
        style={drawerWebviewStyles.container}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

pdf doesn't work on android webview check this issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6488) you may look for other solution like download it and open it with pdf viewer

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a very well known 5 year very old problem, which is that generally android had little abilities to run both a resource hungry app like a browser with a binary resource hungry data type such as application/PDF.

<strike>https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/android---webview-cannot-display-pdf</strike> a dead link to older forum comments.

There are same as a desktop browser 2 possibilities.

1. Save as file download.pdf and call any suitable native pdf handler, but react-native-view-pdf cannot currently load local files in Android.
2. Embed/customise a **simple** maintained js alternate pdf viewer such as

https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js **OR** like cloud based google docs viewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <WebView
  source={{
   uri:
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
     ? 'https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'
     : 'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
  }}
  style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
  useWebKit={true}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  allowFileAccess={true}
  allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
 />
```